# How to use cuda for dictionary inputs?

Tags: pytorch

How can I use pytorch cuda for dictionary inputs like above?

```
train_dataset[0]
>> {'ages': '40대',
 'cust': 'M000034966',
 'sequence_item': ['PD0816', 'PD0796', 'PD0777', 'PD1161'],
 'sequence_timestamp': tensor([1.6108e+09, 1.6108e+09, 1.6108e+09, 1.6108e+09]),
 'sex': '여성',
 'target': tensor(0.),
 'target_item': 'PD1468',
 'target_timestamp': tensor(1.6108e+09)}
```

For categorical features like sex, I encode and embed them in my custom model. It is just a string type in dictionary, not a tensor, so when should I use .cuda()?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing like [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/module-dictionary-to-gpu-or-cuda-device/86482)?
It seems that each dictionary variables can be mapped to a GPU.